# trouble while installing nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I was trying to install Nvidia driver till I got this error :

```
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
     installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING   
     THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver         
     download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

[image]

```
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
     '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find            
     suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available   
     on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

[image]

Then I tried his method :

```
sudo killall Xorg
```

And I got :

```
Xorg: no process found
```

But I still get the same error while trying to install Nvidia, what should I do ??

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, what driver version? Did you try the 'additional drivers' method on Software & Updates?